# scala. higher order function calling by name. does it make sense

Tags: scala

Just want to clarify. If we use `higher-order function` (f. that accepts another function as argument). Does it make any sense specify `"=>"` sign to call it `by-name`. It seems arg-function is calling `by-name` anyhow?

There is an example:

```
// 1.
  // the function that accepts arg-function with: two int params and returning String
  // the function passing v1 & v2 as parameters to arg-function, invoking arg-function 2 times, connecting the result to one string
  def takeFunction1(f: (Int, Int) => String, v1:Int, v2:Int ): String = {
     f(v1, v2) + f(v1, v2)
  }

  // 2. same as #1 but calling arg-function by-name
  def takeFunction2(f: => ((Int, Int) => String), v1:Int, v2:Int ): String = {
    f(v1, v2) + f(v1, v2)
  }    

  def aFun(v1:Int, v2:Int) : String = {
    (v1 + v2).toString
  }

  // --

 println( takeFunction1( aFun, 2, 2) )

 println( takeFunction2( aFun, 2, 2) )
```

And what if I want to call it like this ?:

```
println( takeFunction2( aFun(2,2)), ... ) // it tries to evaluate immediately when passing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that if you pass as the first argument a call to a function that returns the `(Int, Int) => String` value to use, this call to the generator function is evaluated only once with pass-by-value, compared to being evaluated each time the argument is used in the case of pass-by-name.

Rather contrived example:

```
var bar = 0

def fnGen() = {
  bar += 1
  def myFun(v1:Int, v2:Int) = {
    (v1 + v2).toString
  }
  myFun _
}
```

Now run some calls of your methods above using fnGen:

```
scala> println( takeFunction1( fnGen(), 2, 2) )
44

scala> bar
res1: Int = 1

scala> println( takeFunction2( fnGen(), 2, 2) )
44

scala> bar
res3: Int = 3
```

As you can see, calling `takeFunction1` increments `bar` only once, while calling `takeFunction2` increments `bar` twice.

Comment: That's interesting, the way you are passing parameters from fnGen to myFun. Like fnGen does not have any parameters defined (on first glance), but since fnGen returns 'partially applied function' which made by using "_" on myFun, then it makes fnGen returns the function that's able to apply parameters, that eventually make fnGen takes parameters, and then takeFunction1/2 passes those parameters to it. Make sense.

Comment: I've added an example in my repo based on this q/a: https://github.com/Sergey80/scala-samples/blob/master/src/calling_by_name/CallingFunctionByNameTest.scala

Answer (score 0):

The argument that you're passing by name is `aFun`; that's a valid expression, and it does get evaluated both times that `takeFunction2` uses it, but since it's just a variable, and you're not doing anything else with it, "evaluating" it is not very meaningful. (It just evaluates to the same value both times.) For pass-by-name to behave differently from pass-by-value, you have to pass in an impure expression (one that has side-effects, or that can evaluate to different values on successive calls, or whatnot).