# Is map() call by name?

Tags: scala

Is [map](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html#map[B](f:A=%3EB):Seq[B]) working by call by name? The function which I pass to a map is executed over the elements in the sequence. Since it is being evaluated not during invocation, I believe it is call by name. But I am not able to figure it out from the syntax.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18523414/scala-higher-order-function-calling-by-name-does-it-make-sense

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scala. higher order function calling by name. does it make sense](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18523414/scala-higher-order-function-calling-by-name-does-it-make-sense)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the specification for "By Name Parameters":

> ### 4.6.2 By-Name Parameters
>
> `ParamType ::= ‘=>’ Type`
>
> The type of a value parameter may be prefixed by `=>`, e.g. `x: => T`.
>   The type of such a parameter is then the parameterless method type `=>
>   T`. This indicates that the corresponding argument is not evaluated at
>   the point of function application, but instead is evaluated at each
>   use within the function. That is, the argument is evaluated using
>   call-by-name

Then no, it isn't "call by name" by definition.

`map` is a higher order function, it takes a function as input from `A` to `B`. It isn't "call by name" as it takes in a type parameter `A`.

What must be understood is that call by name is not evaluated at the call site, but only upon invocation. It is merely syntax sugar for passing in `() => A` (A `Function0[A]`), a function which takes no parameters and returns `A`.

Comment: oh, didn't see you there.. :)

Comment: @TzachZohar I snicked in from behind :P.